# Is there a way in WPF MVVM to refresh all the controls within a TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is there a way in WPF MVVM to refresh all the controls within a TabControl.
I know that I can refresh each individual control by calling
PropertyChanged(nameof(property))

and if I pass no parameter it refreshes all the controls on the View.

However I was wondering if anyone knows of a way to refresh only the controls within a single page on a TabControl on the View

Answer (score 3):

You have it backwards, you don't refresh controls with MVVM. Instead you make your mutable model/view model properties observable, bind them to your view and let everything refresh itself when it needs to.

Comment: Yes, but it only knows to refresh itself when the public property gets set and implements INotifyPropertyChanged which means it needs to be called for each property.

Comment: Yes, and? Just code correctly and you won't have any problems.

Comment: @Blindy the private properties that the public properties are based on have been updated for 20 properties. I'm trying to avoid calling OnPropertyChanged 20 times. It's not very maintainable if I want to add more in the future.

Comment: Yet that is still the correct way of doing it, you just don't need to do it by hand. See, once you start explaining why you don't want to do the correct thing, we get to the heart of the issue: an XY problem. You have entire frameworks like `ReactiveUI` that handle chains of property notifications for you (`ObservableAsPropertyHelper`), as well as the full power of Roslyn source generation at your disposal. The answer stays the same: simply code correctly, and everything falls into place.

Comment: "simply code correctly" - that's a handy catch-all answer that could be used to answer almost every question on SO.